# When do NFS mount major/minor device ids change?

Tags: nfs, device

I have a NFS folder mounted in `/mnt/data`:

`# mountpoint -d /mnt/data/
0:25`

When should I expect the major and minor device IDs to change? Reboot? Remount? Random?

I know they did change at least once from `0:26` to `0:25`, however I don't know what has triggered it (I only noticed it after a few reboots/remounts when I went to debug why my log watching utility went crazy rereading old files).

Comment: Depends on your OS, version, NFS client, and any number of other factors.  You probably want to find another way to do whatever you're *actually* trying to do.

Comment: Also, are you setting fsid in your /etc/exports or letting it pick one? may be a factor as well.

Comment: @Aaron I'll take a look at that..

Comment: @womble ubuntu 14.04.2 (nfs-common 1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1)